# image resize on upload imagemagick

Tags: php, .htaccess, image-processing, imagemagick

I have an uploading system on my website which detects whether an image is larger than a certain size and if so resizes it to be that size, using the code below:

```
<?php
if($count >= "1"){
    echo "<h3>The Name : ".$_POST['textfield']. " already exists. </h3>";
    echo "<h3>Please choose a unique name for this photo</h3>";
}else{  
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";



    if (file_exists("uploads/images/photography/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo "<h3>".$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. </h3>";
      }
    else
      {

// Temporary upload image name 
$original_image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 

// Get the image dimensions 
$size=getimagesize( $original_image ); 

if((($size[0])<1600) || (($size[1])<1600)){

$new_image = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/images/photography/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


echo "File uploaded<br><br>"; 

echo "<img src=\"watermark.php?path=".$new_image."\" width=\"900\"><br><br>"; 

}else{

// Name to save the image as - in this case the same as the original 
$new_image = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 

// Maximum image width 
$max_width = "1600"; 

// Maximum image height 
$max_height = "1600"; 

// Resize the image and save 
exec("convert -size {$size[0]}x{$size[1]} $original_image -thumbnail $max_widthx$max_height $new_image"); 

echo "File uploaded<br><br>"; 

echo "<img src=\"watermark.php?path=".$new_image."\" width=\"900\"><br><br>"; 

$copy = copy($new_image, "uploads/images/photography/".$new_image);
$unlink = unlink($new_image);

}

      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/images/photography/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

      $date = date("d/m/y");

      $query  = mysql_query ('INSERT INTO  `ap_photos_list` ( `photo_id` ,  `category_id` ,  `subcategory_id` ,  `photo_name` ,  `photo_size` ,  `upload_date` ,  `filename` ) VALUES ("",  "'.$_REQUEST['category'].'",  "'.$_REQUEST['sub_category'].'",  "'.$_POST['textfield'].'",  "'.($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024).'KB",  "'.$date.'",  "'. $_FILES["file"]["name"].'")');

      $sizes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ap_sizes ORDER BY id ASC");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sizes)){
            $query  = mysql_query ('INSERT INTO  `ap_photos` ( `photo_id` ,  `category_id` ,  `subcategory_id` ,  `photo_name` ,  `photo_size` ,  `upload_date` ,  `filename` , `price` , `size` ) VALUES ("",  "'.$_REQUEST['category'].'",  "'.$_REQUEST['sub_category'].'",  "'.$_POST['textfield'].'",  "'.($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024).'KB",  "'.$date.'",  "'. $_FILES["file"]["name"].'" , "'.$row['price'].'" , \''.$row['size'].'\')');
      }
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "<h3>Invalid file</h3>";
  }
}
?>
```

However one the following errors or problems occur:

- I get the following errors:

  1. `Warning: copy(DSC00103.JPG) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs/ap-photo/admin/new_photo.php on line 220`
  2. `Warning: unlink(DSC00103.JPG) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs/ap-photo/admin/new_photo.php on line 221`
- Or it just does not transfer the image

Both of these outcomes suggest that the image that I am uploading does not exist?!?

Any suggestions for a solution would be gratefully received.

**UPDATE 1**

The .htaccess file I use to protect files for copyright purposes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} $
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|JPG)$ - [L,F]
ErrorDocument 403 /admin/uploads/error-docs/403.shtml
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have gone through the code and identified that the problem is between:

- `exec("convert -size {$size[0]}x{$size[1]} $original_image -thumbnail $max_widthx$max_height $new_image");`

and

- `$copy = copy($new_image, "/homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs/ap-photo/admin/uploads/images/photography/".$new_image);
  $unlink = unlink($new_image);`

I doubt it is the echos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

1/ displaying any errors during upload with the php errors: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

2/ Display the variables with echo at the different stages to see what they contain.

e.g.

```
$original_image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
echo "original image = $original_image<br>";
```

3/ Isolate the individual parts of the code and check each step works.

Editted answer:

To be honist I did not read the Imagemagick code!

```
-size {$size[0]}x{$size[1]} is not required
```

I write my code like this which makes it a bit easier to error check the Imagemagick code as you can add an echo to show the contents of $cmd

```
$cmd = "$original_image -thumbnail $max_widthx$max_height ";
exec(" convert $cmd $new_image");
```

Imagemagick is not great for error checking but you can add this:

```
$array=array(); 
echo "<pre>"; 
$cmd = "$original_image -thumbnail $max_widthx$max_height ";
exec(" convert $cmd $new_image 2>&1", $array);  
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br></pre>";
```

$new_image just needs to be the relative path to the save location with the image name.

Comment: 1. There are no errors in the upload  
2. I'll try that  
3. I believe the error is coming from the exec() function

Comment: all I get is the same two errors which are in my question and this `Array
(
)

1`

Comment: I have checked all the variables they all exist.

Comment: It is strange you are not getting any errors at all and the 1 means fail. I assume Imagemagick has worked for you before?

Comment: Yes I used this same script on another website all worked fine

Comment: I should have said have you used Imagemagick on this site before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11393/discussion-between-david-passmore-and-bonzo)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

- Is the directory to which you're trying to save writable? (uploads/images/photography)
- Is the image larger than what your PHP settings would allow? (usually in php.ini, upload_max_filesize)

EDIT

You'll need the absolute path to your upload location in your "copy" script, which *should* start with something like

```
/homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with the .htaccess file i use to protect the copyright of all my pictures but this doesn't seem to affect it even when i delete these files it does not upload and transfer.

Comment: Nope that does not work. I think the error comes from the $new_image after the exec() function. the copy() cannot identify it. see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Seems your upload_max_filesize is set to the default 2MB. Please set a .htaccess with the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          120M
```

For more info refer to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: it is set to 40M at the moment which is sufficient for all the photos